# How to fix this jquery function to work in IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I am relatively new with Javascript but managed to somehow get this code to work on chrome, firefox, safari but it doesn't properly on IE.  First look at this code and then after that I will explain what seems to be not working:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.domain.com/test/wtf.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                var transition = 'slow';
                var target1 = $('#flash1');
                var target2 = $('#flash2');
                var target3 = $('#box2');
                var target4 = $('#tble');
                var target5 = $('.links');
                var target6 = $('#wording');
                target1.delay(1000).fadeIn();
                target2.delay(2000).fadeIn();
                target3.delay(3000).fadeIn();
                target4.delay(4000).fadeIn();
                target5.delay(5000).fadeIn();
                target6.delay(6000).fadeIn();
            });
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#this_is_button").click(function () {
                    $("#box2").hide();
                    $("#tble").hide();
                    $(".links").hide();
                    $("#second_pls").show();
                    $("#box2").css("background", "black");
                })
            });
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#what_close").click(function () {
                    $("#second_pls").hide();
                    $("#tble").show();
                    $(".snap").show();
                    $(".links").show();
                    $("#box").css({
                        backgroundImage: "url('/test/img.jpg')",
                        backgroundSize: "800px"});
                    });
                });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="box">
            <div id="box2" style="display:none"></div>
            <div id="wording" style="display:none">
                <label id="flash1" style="display:none">Hello</label>
                <label id="flash2" style="display:none">World</label>
            </div>
            <div id="tble" style="display:none">This is a table</div>
            <div id="second_pls" style="display:none">Hello Hello Hello, is this working? come on already?!!
                <input type="button" id="what_close" value="Close">
            </div>
            <div class="links" style="display:none">
                <input type="button" id="this_is_button" value="Sample">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
 #box {
    background-color: #000000;
    height: 350px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 800px;
 }
 #box2 {
    background-image: url("/test/img.jpg");
    background-size: 800px;
    height: 550px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 800px;
    position: absolute;
}
#wording {
    position: relative;
    color: #999999;
    font-size: 15px;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding-top: 30px;     
    }
#tble {
        margin-top: 180px;
        position: absolute;
}
#second_pls {
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-top: 310px;
        position: absolute;
}
.links {
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-top: 310px;
        position: absolute;
}
```

So what is the part that doesn't seem to function when the page is rendered in IE? It seems that the fadeIn, fadeOut, hide and show parts are not rendering in IE except #flash1, and #flash2 work, the rest of the fade in, fade out don't work.  I am ripping my hair out not understanding why those two would work but not the rest.

I used BrowserStack and it seems that on Windows XP using IE 8 it renders properly with the exception of properly rendering the background image.  But on Windows 7 using IE 8, it works the same way as it does on Windows XP but when using IE 9 it gives me the current issue.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's `<script type='text/javascript'` in there for? (just after your stylesheet link)

Comment: Sorry that was a typo.  I fixed it but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Do you really indent your code like that in production? You know, lots of people will skip this question just by lookin' at the code...

Comment: Sorry man, not sure how to indent that.  How do I do it? I'll fix it.

Comment: You can start with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style, and http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html

Comment: @ariel - http://jsbeautifier.org/ This is how you indent your code quickly. It supports JavaScript and HTML.

Comment: @derek: Thanks, I will begin using jsbeautifier.  Thanks for the indentation as well.

Comment: @ariel - Also it seems like you have an extra `</div>` at the end. Indents help you find those little errors very easily.

Comment: @derek: OK, let me review the code and see where the extra one is coming form.

Comment: @derek: Yes, there was an extra one.  Removed it.

Comment: You assign 3 document ready handlers in separate scripts, which is allowed in jquery and not what is causing the problem here, but kind of messy and unnecessary. The scripts could be combined like this http://jsfiddle.net/R2KXw/

Comment: Declare a proper doctype in the HTML, so it won't load in quirks mode.

Comment: but isn't <!doctype html> enough for html5?

Answer (score 2):

It seems the problem arise from incorrect syntax:

```
 $("#box").css({
               backgroundImage: "url('/test/img.jpg')",
               backgroundSize: "800px", //<-- extra comma
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bfcZd/3/

vs.

http://jsfiddle.net/bfcZd/4/

Comment: I've just tested the last fiddle using IE9 (IE8 and IE7 emulation) it works. Which version of IE are you using?

Comment: Thanks for doing that.  I am using IE9 and also tried it on IE8.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the CSS declarations for the two divs that are working. I suspect they may be position:relative or have some other property that is causing them to render differently (properly) while the other ones fail. Could you provide the CSS that you have set for the divs in your example. It will help us troubleshoot a little better, but without seeing it, this is my hunch.

Comment: Thanks @ckaufman.  Let me post the CSS. Will update you here when it's posted up.

Comment: I added the CSS. Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Is there any debugging tools I can use for IE?

Answer (score 0):

add this meta tag inside your `<head></head>`

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">
```

should work then.

i have it here in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Morlock0821/XtyWC/