# How do I see error messages for JavaScript/JQuery code in IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I am new to javascript and have been working overnight to see how I can fix this error on IE:  Here's the question I asked here yesterday:  [How to fix this jquery function to work in IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13793717/how-to-fix-this-jquery-function-to-work-in-ie#comment18972102_13793717)

After spending more than 20 hours I still can't find out why it wouldn't render parts of my page properly.

At the very least I thought I could find a way to get the errors so I can fix them or do a separate javascript file just for IE, but no luck.

How do I see error messages for my script?

I used F12 to see the developer console but no help there, it won't even tell me what's wrong.

I am using IE 8 and 9.

I know that there could be many things wrong with this and I appreciate your patience in advance for helping me out.  Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried refreshing the cache on the f12 tools and then reloading the page?

Comment: If there are no error messages in the developer console then you may not have any JavaScript errors. Perhaps something else is wrong.

Comment: @user1394965 Thanks for replying.  I did refresh and I also used BrowserStack and it looks messed up.

Comment: @jayBlanchard, Thats what I am thinking too, but I guess I will have to break the code bit by bit and start seeing what is at fault.

Comment: Do you have a link to the web page, or are you running it locally?

Comment: @xeano, it's being run locally.  Not sure if I can share this stuff via a web page yet.

Comment: Is this a JavaScript issue or a rendering issue?  Does the HTML code validate?  Explorer likes to choke on invalid HTML and render a mess.

Comment: Let me render it W3C and see if any errors pop up.

Comment: @spark672, this is what i got:  Line 20, Column 8: Element head is missing a required instance of child element title.
        <script type='text/javascript'>

Comment: @ariel - what seems to not be working? I looked at your code from the previous answer, and it seems to work just as intended here [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/zVp5A/1/), apart from the fact that some elements, like `#box`, are never shown, as they are kept `dispay:none` the whole time, but that is just human error ?

Comment: @adeneo, give me a few minutes to see if I can put it on the web that way it's much clearer.

Comment: @adeneo, i got access to a server, give me a few more minutes to upload stuff to it.

Comment: I can tell you that it works fine in IE10 ;) I can see what you mean about IE9 - I'll have a look at it

Comment: Please don't spam/abuse comments like that.  Just append your OP using the "edit" link.

Comment: The [HTML validation errors are pretty clear](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fpinnaclemri.com%2Fplate%2Fie.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0).  Just fix them all.

Comment: @sparky672 I am not sure what it means by the <script> part and not sure what it means by the </head> tag.

Comment: <script type='text/javascript'> use double qoutes. not single: <script type="text/javascript">.

Comment: @xeano, yes fixed that part.  thanks.

Comment: Double or single quotes don't matter in this context.  _"Line 10, Column 8: Element head is missing a required instance of child element **title**."_ ~ It means you are missing the required `<title>` element.

Comment: @sparky672 i fixed that as well but i think the issue might be with the body onload, which i don't understand.

Comment: I think I found your whole issue.  When I copied your source code into my text editor, I found a bunch of invalid invisible characters.  Did you cut/paste your JavaScript from someplace like a web-page?  The invisibles only appear in front of your custom written scripts in the `head` and nowhere else.  This could certainly explain a lot, including the validation errors.  Go back to your editor and delete indentations on every single line in the `head` section, then re-indent each line from scratch.

Comment: @sparky672, yes I cut stuff from other pages to customize the code.  Wow, so i wasted 1 whole day not knowing that that was the issue.  How do i fix this? Thanks a lot for going far to help you.

Comment: I use BBEdit on Mac and turn on the option for "Show Invisibles".   If your text editor can't do this, just do what I said... remove all leading space from every single line of code in the `head` and re-indent properly using your space bar or tab key.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20894/discussion-between-ariel-and-sparky672)

Comment: I removed all the invisible characters for you and pasted all of your JavaScript code into [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HFHvn/).  You should have no trouble cleanly cutting and pasting out from jsFiddle.  Let me know how it goes.  http://jsfiddle.net/HFHvn/

Comment: This one contains the entire page in the body panel:  http://jsfiddle.net/HFHvn/1/

Comment: @sparky672 i added the entire page code and i still get the same issue.  yikes!

Comment: No you do not!  [See the validator errors](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fpinnaclemri.com%2Fplate%2Fie.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.3).  You have gotten past the invisible character issue and now page validation is completing instead of stopping.  Each error is self explanatory... `</label6>` is not a valid tag, etc.

Comment: And you have one nasty bad invisible character immediately after `</html>`.  Delete the entire last line and manually re-type "`</html>`"

Comment: @sparky672, i fixed the </html> close tag but the rest of the errors seem unrelated.  Are they important to fix?

Comment: Since there is no such tag as `</label6>`, I'd say that's a pretty important one to fix. (Note the "6").

Comment: Ok fixed that as well, possible for you to come in chat room?

Comment: I'm posting the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have invalid HTML including many invisible characters within the `head` section which is also blocking the [W3C HTML Validator](http://validator.w3.org/) from getting past the first few errors.

When I copied your source code into my text editor, I found a bunch of invalid invisible characters. Did you cut/paste your JavaScript from someplace like a web-page? The invisibles only appear in front of your custom written scripts in the `<head>` and nowhere else. This could certainly explain a lot, including the validation error about a misplaced `</head>` tag. Go back to your editor and delete the indentations on every single line within the entire `<head></head>` section, then re-indent each line from scratch.

I also see an invalid closing tag, `</label6>`.

Remove the invisible characters, fix the invalid HTML, and see what IE does.

---

Moving forward, get yourself a powerful text editor that will allow you to see invisible characters so you can delete them and properly indent as needed. Otherwise, I recommend re-typing your code rather than cutting & pasting.

Comment: Thanks @sparky672 for all your help.  I can't believe nobody else noticed this.  Regardless, for the first time i realized that spacing creates issues, i thought space was irrelevant.  Is that not true? if not, what resrouces can i use to perfect myself in that area?

Comment: @ariel: Spacing & tabs _are_ usually irrelevant to the processing of code.  Your problem was not "spacing", your problem was all the invisible characters you picked up by cutting & pasting from various webpages/blogs, etc.  Get yourself a powerful text editor that will allow you to see invisible characters so you can delete them.  Otherwise, I recommend re-typing your code rather than cutting & pasting.

Answer (score 1):

For JavaScript errors, the best is to see the 'Console' tab for records.

If IE's one isn't showing anything, maybe you could try using FireBug Lite, adding the following script after `<head>` (YES, put it as first thing, so it loads first than anything else).

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite.js"></script>`

On side note, maybe isn't a JS problem and yes something about running code locally. IE has some policies that  mostly block client-side code from running. (Remember those annoying ActiveX prompts?). Check Intranet configuration on Settings.

Comment: Thanks @raphaelddl, but what will this firebug snippet do?

Comment: @ariel It will create a Firebug Developer Console (just like Firefox Plugin), but made with JS. This comes handy with IE's Web Developer Tools aren't of much help. By the way, I've added a side-note with another possibility, which can also be the local settings blocking some part of your JS if it is not printing any error on Console.